# Find coordinates with bearing from one point and distance from another.

Tags: coordinates

I am trying to find coordinates of point $X$ if I know distance from point $A$ and bearing from point $B$, and a line from point $B$ intersects on a circle which radius equals the distance from point $A$ (see images). Is it possible to find it with a formula? Thanks a lot!

The knowns (for Image 1):

Point A coordinates - Latitude: 37.8886778; Longitude: 23.8044972

Point B coordinates - Latitude: 37.9214949; Longitude:  23.9189052

r = 14 nm

d (bearing where 0=North and 90=East) = 50 degrees

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]
If points A and B were the same, I would use the following code to find Point X:

```
distance = distance / EARTHRADIUS;
heading = deg2rad(heading);
fromLat = deg2rad(latitude);
fromLng = deg2rad(longitude);
cosDistance = Math.cos(distance);
sinDistance = Math.sin(distance);
sinFromLat = Math.sin(fromLat);
cosFromLat = Math.cos(fromLat);
sinLat = cosDistance * sinFromLat + sinDistance * cosFromLat * Math.cos(heading);
dLng = Math.atan2(sinDistance * cosFromLat * Math.sin(heading), cosDistance - sinFromLat * sinLat);
POINT X = rad2deg(Math.asin(sinLat)),rad2deg(fromLng + dLng)
```

So, I guess it is a question of finding the distance between B and X.

Comment: Yes, this is a very simple exercise. Do you know how to use trig functions? Note though that a "bearing from a point" makes no sense - is it $50$ degrees measured relative to the positive $x$-axis or is it $50$ degrees measured relative to the positive $y$-axis?

Comment: Bearing meaning heading using 360 degrees circle, i.e. 50 degrees being NE direction. By coordinates, I also meant Latitude/Longitude, if it matters.

Comment: That is not clear in your diagram. In any event, the cosine and sine functions with a coefficient of $r$ and an argument of $50$ degrees give you your $x$ and $y$ coordinates respectively.

Comment: If I had one point, which was the centre of the circle and bearing from it, I would use something like: `X = Cx + (r * cosine(angle)) ; Y = Cy + (r * sine(angle))`. Please look at the image. The problem is a bit different, especially the second image.

Comment: Do you know coordinates of $B$?

Comment: Yes. I added them to the original question.

Comment: Also, added at the bottom how to find Point X if points A and B were the same.